# Compiler error trying to work out what to put in an Either.Match lambda

Tags: c#, functional-programming, language-ext

I have a situation in which I have a bunch of methods that all require the same code at the beginning. In order to reduce duplication, I want to move that code into a general helper method that would take a lambda parameter for the case-specific code.

The scenario involves loyalty cards, which are issued by card issuers. All methods take a card issuer Id and some JSON (serialised as a string as it came in from an API). The JSON is deserialised to an object (to make it easier to work with). If all went well, the method returns a success message (a `string`), and if there was a problem, returns the error (also a `string`).

One example of a method is to check if a card is active. The JSON contains the card number.

I'm using Language-Ext, and have static utility methods that return `Either<string, T>` with `<T>` being specific to the method.

My intention was to have an overall method that (as well as the issuer Id and the serialised JSON) take a delegate that does the case-specific code. My current attempt looks like this...

```cs
static async Task<string> Execute<T>(string issuerId, 
                                     string json, 
                                     Func<RequestDto<T>, Task<Either<string, string>>> specific) =>
  // First call the helper method, see below
  (await GetDto<T>(issuerId, json))
    .Match(async requestDto =>
      // We got the incoming data OK, so call the case-specific method
      (await specific(requestDto))
      .Match(response => {
        // Everything went fine, return the response
        return response;
      }, msg => {
        // There was a problem (invalid issuer Id, etc), return the error message
        return msg;
      }),
     // There was a problem getting the DTO, return the error message
     x => x);
```

This relies on the following records and helper methods...

```cs
record CardIssuer(string Id, string EncryptionKey);
record RequestDto<T>(CardIssuer CardIssuer, T Dto);

static async Task<Either<string, RequestDto<T>>> GetDto<T>(string issuerId, string json) =>
  // First get the card issuer
  await from cardIssuer in GetCardIssuer(issuerId).ToAsync()
        // Deserialise the JSON to a case-specific object
        let dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json)
        // Wrap the two into something the specific method can accept
        select new RequestDto<T>(cardIssuer, dto);

static Either<string, CardIssuer> GetCardIssuer(string id) =>
  // Would get the card issuer from the database, or return Left if not found
  id == "1" ? new CardIssuer("1", "abc") : new CardIssuer(id, "def");
```

An example of a case-specific method would be to check if a card is valid...

```cs
record CheckCardRequest(string cardSerialNumber);

static async Task<Either<string, string>> CheckCard(RequestDto<CheckCardRequest> dto) =>
  // Would check the card against the database and return something more realistic
  dto.Dto.cardSerialNumber == "11"
    ? Right<string, string>("Ok")
    : Left<string, string>("Bleah");
```

This provides a complete example of what I want to do, although it is obviously very simplified. The real code is all `async` as it involves database calls, and uses `Either` as there are many places where things can go wrong. I simplified all of that to provide a complete example.

My problem is with the lambda `x => x` at the very end of the `Execute` method.

I get a red underline on the second `x` with a compiler error "*Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.*"

As a general rule, I understand why this error can be raised, but I don't understand why I get it here. I thought that the lambda `x => x` was returning a value, so was an expression, not a statement.

I've tried changing it to `x => return x` and other variations, but just get different compiler errors.

Anyone able to explain what I need to do to get this working?

P.S. This is related to a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060425/is-there-a-way-of-passing-extra-data-to-the-left-lambda-in-match-without-having), but as it's quite different, I thought I should open a new question for this one. If I can get this working, then it would provide a good solution for what I asked there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that due to type mismatch (`async` lambda `async requestDto =>...` returns `Task<string>`'s so the second parameter of `Match` should also have the same return type) the `Unit Match(Action<R> Right, Action<L> Left, Action Bottom = null)` overload is selected. After fixing this (by changing `x => x` to `x => Task.FromResult(x)`) you will need to `await` the match result. And then you can simplify/refactor a bit with the final method looking like this:

```
static async Task<string> Execute<T>(string issuerId,
    string json,
    Func<RequestDto<T>, Task<Either<string, string>>> specific) =>
    await (await GetDto<T>(issuerId, json))
        .Match(
            async requestDto => (await specific(requestDto)).Match(s => s, s =>s),
            Task.FromResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it had to be something simple, but was breaking my head trying to work out what